# save objects of a function without printing in R

Tags: r, function

I have a function with several elements, that I'd like were accessible (`a1`, `a2` and `f1`). To this end, I added a list in the return of the function.  `return(list(a1=a2,a2=a2,f1=f1))`

however when I run the function, there are some that I would like not to be printed. Such as `a2` and `f1`. So my question is  do I access my objects as `a2` or `f1` without be printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign the result of your function to a variable using `<-`. For example, if your function is `foo`, simply doing `foo()` will print the resulting list to screen, but `res <- foo()` will not, and you can access `res$a1`, `res$a2` and `res$f1`.

In case you want to print some of the variables, you explicitly call `print()`. For example, put at the end of your function:

```
print(a1)
return(list(a1=a1, a2=a2, f1=f1))
```

Sometimes we want to silently return all function values. We could do

```
invisible(list(a1=a1, a2=a2, f1=f1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if i got it right but you can call the function and assign the output to a variable so that you can choose later what to print.

Naming the list will help you too.

**EDIT:** Added the name of the list using @cuttlefish44 advice.

```
SomeFunctionName <- function(){

    a <- 1
    b <- rep(1,10)
    c <- rep("aaa",20)
    d <- list(a = a,b = b,c = c)
    return(d)
}

var <- SomeFunctionName()

var$a
var$b
var$c
```

Naming the list will help you too.

Comment: `d <- list(a,b,c); names(d) <- c("a","b","c")` is equivalent to `d <- list(a = a, b = b , c = c)`.